# Golang GSheet get range of cells where cell is blank for a given column and update them with value

Tags: go, google-sheets

I am trying to fetch a gsheet detail where there are 3 columns say column A, B and C.

```
   A    B    C
0  1    2    3
1  4    5    6
2  7    8
3  9    10
4  11   12
```

Here I need to fetch data from row no. 2 till the end where the column C value is blank along with row indexes.

```
readRange := "Sheet1!A:C"
   resp1, err := srv.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(spreadsheetId, readRange).Do()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve data from sheet: %v", err)
    }
    if len(resp1.Values) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("No data found.")
    } else {
        for _, row := range resp1.Values {
            fmt.Printf("%s, %s\n", row[0], row[1])
        }
    }
```

So how can I apply filter here in Golang to get the rows from row no.2 where column C value is blank.
And later update those cells with some value.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your goal of `how can I apply filter here in go to get the rows from row no.2 where column C value is blank.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: @Tanaike Have updated my goal? It's not about poor english it's about understanding the query with code language in context